# Nginx server on Google App Engine stopped working suddenly

Tags: http, google-app-engine, nginx, google-cloud-platform

Starting yesterday, my google app engine app stopped working.

I have started seeing hundreds of these in the `nginx.error` log stream:

[image]

One of these, for example,

> [error] 32#0: *506755 upstream prematurely closed connection while
>   reading response header from upstream, client: 169.XXX.XXX.XXX, server:
>   , request: "PUT /parse/classes/_Installation/Vt22FpBXIm HTTP/1.1",
>   upstream:
>   "http://172.XXX.XXX.XXX:8080/parse/classes/_Installation/Vt22FpBXIm", host:
>   “my-project-id.appspot.com"

I have used `XXX`s to obfuscate ips. 
I have absolutely no clue what’s happening, I barely know what nginx is.

No changes were made to clients nor server in the last week. These errors started yesterday. Requests fail with `502 Bad gateway`.

Do you have any clue what might be happening, and why? Where should I look to debug this issue? I found no relevant information in logs whatsoever.

Comment: what's on your upstream block inside your nginx.conf file? This is probably the upstream provider that is down, not nginx.

Comment: @peixotorms I have no access to any nginx.conf file. These are managed by google app engine. I’m not even confident with the term “upstream provider”. Yesterday I made a new deploy of the app, without changing a single line, and somehow the error disappeared. But I am still curious to know what happened.

Comment: @natario Seeing the same problem

Comment: @DaveBensonPhillips Sorry I can't help. But please add more info if you get some.

Comment: I am also seeing this issue. I'm running app engine standard and recently with low load I've been running into this issue more and more. The active instances start erroring out and our clients are hit with 502's until I go in and manually stop / delete those instances... 

Can't really find anything in the logs other than this error that pops up after the first 502.

[error] 32#32: *294 upstream prematurely closed connection while reading response header from upstream....